# JsonParser Error schema for Hbase Sink Connector

Tags: java, apache-kafka, hbase, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using hbase sink connector for kafka (https://github.com/mravi/kafka-connect-hbase) and using JsonEventParser, and i got some problem here.
The connector returns error :

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: JsonConverter with schemas.enable requires "schema" and "payload" fields and may not contain additional fields. If you are trying to deserialize plain JSON data, set schemas.enable=false in your converter configuration.
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:308)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:453)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:287)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:198)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
    at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

But im really sure that i have include the schema in the producer messages.
Here's my message sample :

```
{"schema":{"type": "struct","optional": false,"name": "record","fields": [{"type": "string","optional": true, "field": "id"},{"type": "string","optional":true,"field": "name"}]},"payload": {"id": "8","name": "test"}}
```

This is my properties file :

```
bootstrap.servers=xxxx.xxxx.xx.xx:xxxx

    group.id=connect-cluster

    key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter


    key.converter.schemas.enable=true
    value.converter.schemas.enable=true


    internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
    internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
    internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false


    offset.storage.topic=connect-offsets
    offset.storage.replication.factor=1


    config.storage.topic=connect-configs
    config.storage.replication.factor=1


    status.storage.topic=connect-status
    status.storage.replication.factor=1



    offset.flush.interval.ms=10000

    # These are provided to inform the user about the presence of the REST host and port configs 
    # Hostname & Port for the REST API to listen on. If this is set, it will bind to the interface used to listen to requests.
    rest.host.name=xxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx
    rest.port=xxxx

    # The Hostname & Port that will be given out to other workers to connect to i.e. URLs that are routable from other servers.
    rest.advertised.host.name=xxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx
    rest.advertised.port=xxxx


    /* authentication Kerberos */

    # Set to a list of filesystem paths separated by commas (,) to enable class loading isolation for plugins
    # (connectors, converters, transformations). The list should consist of top level directories that include 
    # any combination of: 
    # a) directories immediately containing jars with plugins and their dependencies
    # b) uber-jars with plugins and their dependencies
    # c) directories immediately containing the package directory structure of classes of plugins and their dependencies
    # Examples: 
    #
```

Anyone knows why this error thrown?

Comment: Can you post contents of your connect-standalone.properties file?

Comment: Also, you can consider looking into enhanced version [kafka-hbase-sink connector](https://github.com/nishutayal/kafka-connect-hbase)

Comment: i run this kafka on distributed way. I have posted the properties file content below.

Comment: Have posted an answer. Please check.

Comment: Please show your Kafka console consumer output of the topic with keys included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be due to key converter type. At the moment you have specified:

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

That means, that key and value, both are json type. If the key doesn't have Schema and Payload, it will throw the error.

Hence use String Converter in case of null or string key type.

```
key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
```

Comment: thanks @Nishu thats solve my problem. Can i ask one more? For the schemaless Json, why the connector throws null pointer exception when i set 

key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
value.converter.schemas.enable=false

and this is the messages that i push :
{"id": "9","name": "test"}

Comment: @boy : Thanks for noticing the issue. I am maintaining the hbase connector. I have fixed it and pushed in the github repo. Please use https://github.com/nishutayal/kafka-connect-hbase. Let me know if you face any challenges

Comment: Thanks for the help! now it works with little fixes to apply it to my case.